# Android build issue with 'scan' plugin - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-packages

Android build failing with following exception.

```
Plugin: scan [https://pub.dev/packages/scan]
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDevReleaseAssets'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:devReleaseRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.huawei.hms:scanplus:2.1.0.300.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :scan
> > Could not resolve com.huawei.hms:scanplus:2.1.0.300.
> > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/huawei/hms/scanplus/2.1.0.300/scanplus-2.1.0.300.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/huawei/hms/scanplus/2.1.0.300/scanplus-2.1.0.300.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 2m 59s

Comment: I'm getting the same issues but no solution working for me...

Comment: Did you get any solution to it?

Answer (score -1):

add: maven {url 'http://developer.huawei.com/repo'}
[check your build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yS8R.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).